# What is the best way to remove a large number of documents and compact collection

Tags: mongodb

We have a sharded mongo cluster with 3 Replica Sets and 3 Shards. There is one collection with 400,000,000 documents, on which I have many insert and query operations every day. A few days ago, I found that the disk is almost full, and I have to delete something to release space.

Many people have mentioned that even if we remove documents, disk space will not be released under the WiredTiger engine, because the indexes still exist.

According to the official document, we have found the following ways:

1. Firstly, do db.collection.deleteMany(some condition), and then run db.collection.runCommand("compact") or run db.repairDatabase()
2. Do delete method on primary, remove one secondary node from the cluster, run "compact" command or repairDatabase command, and the put it back, then another secondary, finally step down the primary and run above command as a secondary.

Unfortunately, deleting a large of documents will block other operation such as inserting or updating, which is unacceptable. Is there another better method?